# How to toggle "table group detail" in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008, pivot, ssrs-tablix

Suppose your dataset is

```
Street
Housenumber
InhabitantNumber
InhabitantDataType
InhabitantDataValue
```

So you might have

```
Monkeystreet : 23 : 1 : Name : Bob Smith
Monkeystreet : 23 : 1 : DOB  : 01.01.1950
Monkeystreet : 23 : 2 : Name : Sheila Smith
Monkeystreet : 23 : 2 : MaritalStatus: Married
Monkeystreet : 27 : 1 : Name : John Doe
Goatroad     : 15 : 1 : Name : Sally Mither
Goatroad     : 15 : 1 : DOB  : 02.02.1970
```

**Note**: There can be varying amounts of data per inhabitant

Now I pivot this data

So the columns are

```
Street    : HouseNumber : Inhabitant : InhabitantData
MonkeySt. :    23       :     1      :    Name: BobSmith
                                          DOB : 01.01.1950
                        :     2      :    Name: SheilaSmith
                                         MarSt: Married
          :     27      :     1      :    Name: John Doe
-------------------------------------------------------------
Goatroad  :     15      :     1      :    Name: Sally Mither
                                     :    DOB : 02.02.1970
```

So I have a row grouping on 'streetname' and one on 'housenumber' and the 'inhabitant data' is in a table detail group

How can I make this inhabitant data 'show' or 'hide' with a toggle?

Answer (score 3):

You actually need a third grouping to make the toggle work.  If you group by the InhabitantNumber and then add a toggle to that grouping you will be able to show and hide the InhabitantData.

I used a test query to create the mock data you attached to your post and actually used the report wizard to create this exact behavior.  Here are the steps you can take if you have your query written to create it via the Report Wizard in BIDS:

1. Right-Click Reports folder
2. Click **Add New Report** -> Click **Next** button
3. Setup Data source or reuse existing shared one -> Click **Next** button
4. Paste query into **Query string:** text area or use **Query builder** -> Click **Next** button
5. Choose **Tabular** Report Type -> Click **Next** button
6. Put the following into the **Group** text area using the **Group>** button

   - Street
   - Housenumber
   - InhabitantNumber
   - **Please Note:** The order you put the columns into this box determines the hierarchy of the groupings
7. Put the following into the **Details** text area using the **Details>** button

   - InhabitantDataType
   - InhabitantDataValue
8. Click **Next** button
9. Choose **Stepped** and click **Enable drilldown** checkbox -> Click **Next** button
10. Choose the Table style you prefer -> Click **Next** button
11. Name your report -> Click **Finish** button

This is the easiest way to create the stair stepped / toggle per grouping report.  You could create it manually but just be sure to add that third grouping (by InhabitantNumber) and enable the toggle.

-Paul